# How to change field's name attribute in Symfony Entity type Field

Tags: html, forms, symfony, properties, field

I am new to symfony and have researched a lot but couldn't find a way out

Here is my field add property

```
$builder->add('busownlvlone','entity',array('required'=>false,'class' => 'MyBundle:BusOwnLvlOne','property' => 'business_name','empty_value' => 'Choose an option', 'label' => 'Select Business', 'attr' => array('style' => 'width:230px')
))
```

Here is what I get in View

```
<select style="width:230px" name="mybundle_maptype[busownlvlone]" id="mybundle_maptype_busownlvlone"><option value="">Choose an option</option></select>
```

I want to customize Name property of this field basically I want to turn it into an array sth like

```
name="mybundle_maptype[busownlvlone][]"
```

If I add multiple then the select box changes to multi select so this cannot be an option.Is there any other way out like adding a custom name etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a Custom Element Type which extended Entity Type to resolve this